# Building a query to copy user security settings to another user

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a query to look at a current users security settings, and then copy those settings over to another user. My data is as follows:

```
 Logon_user  Logon_level   Form
 ABOND        1            COST
 ABOND        0            PRODUCTION
 ADOND        0            ACCOUNTING
 ATEMPLE      0            COST
 ATEMPLE      0            PRODUCTION
 ATEMPLE      0            ACCOUNTING
```

I would like to look at the settings for `ABOND` and copy the `logon_level` values to `ATEMPLE`.

Comment: Have you tried creating a T-SQL statement for this?  Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
(
    Logon_User VARCHAR(255)
    , Logon_Level INT
    , Form VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable VALUES 
('ABOND', 1, 'COST')
, ('ABOND', 0, 'PRODUCTION')
, ('ABOND', 0, 'ACCOUNTING')
, ('ATEMPLE', 0, 'COST')
, ('ATEMPLE', 0, 'PRODUCTION')
, ('ATEMPLE', 0, 'ACCOUNTING');

UPDATE MyTable
SET Logon_Level = T.Logon_Level
FROM MyTable 
    INNER JOIN MyTable T ON MyTable.Form = T.Form
WHERE MyTable.Form = T.Form 
    AND T.Logon_User = 'ABOND'
    AND MyTable.Logon_User = 'ATEMPLE';


SELECT *
FROM dbo.MyTable;
```

Comment: That seems to get me very close. the only difference is that i have several users in the database and i want to be able to specify who's security looks like who's. So i could just modify the query each time to make for example Joe's access the same as Mikes. hope that makes sense.  Thanks Max!

Comment: I've added a line to the `UPDATE` statement that specifies the target `Logon_User`.  If this was going to be an ongoing operation, I would create a stored procedure to encapsulate this code, and make it easily accessible.